# Android Service, JavaMail API

Tags: java, android, email, logcat

I have got piece of code working. But when i try to run, the error exception show.
I use broadcast receiver to start service on every reboot, the service monitor sim change and generate email to user. But i have problem when compile, LogCat show the following:

**LogCat**

```
01-24 17:00:14.035: E/SimSerial::(8538): 8944110065486249080
01-24 17:00:14.035: E/Current Sim Serial::(8538): 8944110065486249080
01-24 17:00:14.035: E/Sim Status(8538): Sim no changed !!!
01-24 17:00:14.090: D/dalvikvm(8538): GC_CONCURRENT freed 233K, 9% free 12373K/13575K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 17ms
01-24 17:00:14.090: D/dalvikvm(8538): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538): Could not send email
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:365)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at com.example.newbootservice.GMailSender.send(GMailSender.java:119)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at com.example.newbootservice.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:52)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2531)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-24 17:00:14.120: E/MailApp(8538):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is as below:

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {  

    String storedSimSerial;
    String currentSimSerial;

    @Override  
    public void onCreate() {  
        super.onCreate();    
    }  

    @Override  
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        {
        TelephonyManager telephoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        storedSimSerial = telephoneMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
        Log.e("SimSerial::",storedSimSerial);

        TelephonyManager tmMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        currentSimSerial = tmMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
        Log.e("Current Sim Serial::",currentSimSerial);

        if(currentSimSerial.equals(storedSimSerial))
        {
            Log.e("Sim Status","Sim no changed !!!");
        }             
        else
            Log.e("Sim Status","Sim changed !!!");

            GMailSender m = new GMailSender("gmailusername@gmail.com", "gmailpassword"); 

            String[] toArr = {"blabla@gmail.com", "blabla@hotmail.com"}; 
            m.setTo(toArr); 
            m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com"); 
            m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
            m.setBody("Email body."); 

            try {

              if(m.send()) { 
                Toast.makeText(this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              } else { 
                Toast.makeText(this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              } 
            } catch(Exception e) { 
              //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);

        }
        }
```

**GMailSender.java**

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public GMailSender() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public GMailSender(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 
  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  }

  public String[] getTo(){
      return _to;
  }
  public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
      this._to = toArr;
  }

  public String getFrom(){
      return _from;
  }
  public void setFrom(String _from){
      this._from = _from;
  }

  public String getSubject(){
      return _subject;
  }
  public void setSubject(String string) {
      this._subject = string;
  }

}
```

**JSSEProvider.java**

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Move the network call (`m.send()`) in an AsyncTask to run the "long time" operation in a separate thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the network call (`m.send()`) in an `AsyncTask` to run the "time consuming" operation in a separate thread.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute()");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground() -- Here is the download");
            m.send();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void res)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute()");
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: Ideally yes, if you are lazy, just copy paster it inside your `try { if (m.send() ... } catch()`

Answer (score 2):

Kerry is right.  You cannot perform network I/O on the default thread since Android 3.0

Comment: I had spend one day finding the solution, if there any guide i can refer to because i am new to JavaMail.

Comment: I want my service to send the mail instead of define in another class

Comment: i figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a network on main thread exception. Just off the top of my head after a certain version of android use of network commands on the main thread is not allowed. When I am at my laptop I will update my answer with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Create a AsyncTask outside of onStartCommand

public class GmailAsync extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GMailSender m = new GMailSender("gmailusername@gmail.com", "gmailpassword"); 

        String[] toArr = {"blabla@gmail.com", "blabla@hotmail.com"}; 
        m.setTo(toArr); 
        m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com"); 
        m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
        m.setBody("Email body."); 

        try {

          if(m.send()) { 
              Log.e("Email","Sent successfully !");
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          } else { 
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              Log.e("Email","Was not Sent !");  
          } 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
          //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```